# Property '' does not exist on type 'string' when using makestyles @mui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I have the following code:

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  dialog: {
    root: {
      position: 'absolute'
    },
    backdrop: {
      position: 'absolute'
    },
    paperScrollPaper: {
      overflow: 'visible'
    },
    paper: {
      background: 'none',
      boxShadow: 'none',
      overflow: 'hidden'
    }
  },
}))
    
export const LoadingBackdrop = (props: any) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const backdropProps = {
    disableEscapeKeyDown: true,
    disableAutoFocus: true,
    disableEnforceFocus: true,
    disableScrollLock: true,
    disablePortal: true,
  }
  return (
    <Dialog
      {...backdropProps}
      fullWidth
      className={classes.dialog.root}
      classes={{
        paperScrollPaper: classes.dialog.paperScrollPaper,
        paper: classes.dialog.paper,
        paperFullWidth: classes.dialog.paper
      }}
      BackdropProps={{
        classes: { root: classes.dialog.backdrop }
      }}
      style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
      {...props}
    >
      <Loading />
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

At the LoadingBackDrop component, I am getting the following error from ts eslint:

> Property 'root' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

The same goes for the other uses of classes.dialog, only changing the name of the property...

How can I annotate or type the makestyles function (or the hook call) to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest styles in the way you're doing it - they need to be one level deep. For example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    position: 'absolute'
  },
  backdrop: {
    position: 'absolute'
  },
  paperScrollPaper: {
    overflow: 'visible'
  },
  paper: {
    background: 'none',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  }
}))
```

And:

```
<Dialog
  {...backdropProps}
  fullWidth
  className={classes.root}
  ...
```

Their [Styles documentation](https://mui.com/styles/basics/) have further examples.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you